# publishing artifacts is to slow

Tags: teamcity, agents

At the end of my build log i have the following:

```
[15:16:22]: Publishing artifacts (25m:29s)
[15:16:22]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [automation/artifacts]
[15:16:23]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
```

i tried reading the agents log and got this

```
[2013-05-02 15:16:23,023]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Start: Sending files 
[2013-05-02 15:41:51,214]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Done publishing artifacts to , total files published: 22
```

the size of the artifacts 272 MB.
In the past this part of the process took less then half a minute.

where can i find more data about the operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your network connection between the host with Teamcity master and Teamcity agent. Teamcity saves all the artifacts on master and in the end of the build copy them from agent to master.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a lot of files on the server? I found it would take about 50 mins to complete on a server with a lot of files, however the files would have already been uploaded after 5 mins so I think it might be trying to list all the files or something. When I uploaded the artifacts to another server with less files, it would publish it in around 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

I like to answer this question as recently we faced this problem .

We upgraded our Teamcity from v9.1.7 to V2019.2.1 , In the updated Teamcity there are new requests like `/app/agents/v1/commands/next`  which are increasing traffic for Teamcity . These type of requests will always be polling to Teamcity server from Teamcity agents .

In case your Teamcity server is behind a Apache proxy,  request flow will be like this .

`Client <--> load balancer <--> Apacher <--> Tomcat of Teamcity` .

If Apache in our case is not able to handle that much traffic as now requests are more flowing to Teamcity due to new automated requests then during all interaction to Teamcity requests will be queuing at Apache end hence increasing time for all requests and packet drops .